# glmnet error - non-conformable arguments

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet

I keep running into a stubborn error trying to use the [glmnet stats package](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) as indicated below.

I've tried the limited suggestions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811598/error-in-dropy-rep1-nc-error-for-cv-glmnet-in-glmnet-r-package) (including setting the data as a data.matrix).  I've also attempted to use the "penalty.box" setting described in ?glmnet with no positive results.

```
df = structure(list(term = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), int_rate = c(10.65, 15.27, 15.96, 13.49, 12.69, 7.9, 15.96, 18.64, 21.28, 12.69, 14.65, 12.69, 13.49, 9.91, 10.65, 16.29, 15.27, 6.03, 11.71, 6.03, 15.27, 12.42, 11.71, 11.71, 11.71, 9.91, 16.77, 11.71, 11.71, 7.51, 7.9, 15.96, 8.9, 15.96, 10.65, 9.91, 7.9, 12.42, 12.69, 7.51, 7.9, 18.25, 16.77, 6.03, 9.91, 8.9, 10.65, 6.03, 6.62, 9.91), emp_length = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 3, 8, 9, 4, 1, 5, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, NA, 1, 6, 3, NA, NA, 5, 1, 2, 2, NA, 1, 7, 5, 2, 2, 7, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, NA, 9, NA, NA, 6, NA, 6, NA, 5, 8), annual_inc = c(24000, 30000, 12252, 49200, 80000, 36000, 47004, 48000, 40000, 15000, 72000, 75000, 30000, 15000, 1e+05, 28000, 42000, 110000, 84000, 77385.19, 43370, 105000, 50000, 50000, 76000, 92000, 50004, 106000, 25000, 17108, 75000, 29120, 24044, 34000, 41000, 55596, 45000, 36852, 27000, 68004, 62300, 65000, 55000, 45600, 0000, 1e+05, 27000, 60000, 70000, 80000), delinq_2yrs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), inq_last_6mths = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), outcome = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("term", "int_rate", "emp_length", "annual_inc", "delinq_2yrs", "inq_last_6mths", "outcome"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
X = select(df, -outcome)
Y = df$outcome
X_train = as.matrix(X[1:50,])
Y_train = as.matrix(Y[1:50])

library(glmnet)

model = glmnet(X_train, Y_train, family = "binomial")

summary(model)
```

Here's the error:

```
Error in drop(y %*% rep(1, nc)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for     
function 'drop': Error in y %*% rep(1, nc) : non-conformable arguments
```

The actual dataset is 110 variables and ~1mm observations , but the partial dataset above is producing the same issue.

Any suggestions on debugging approaches for this?

Comment: Suspect you should not be doing `dep_var = data.matrix(train$outcome)`. More probably just use `dep_var = train$outcome`. Also provide library call for package that has `select`. There may be a function that allows minus signs in front of unquoted column names but that looks very "non-standard".

Comment: I attempted that solution earlier, but that didn't solve the issue.   Any clues now that I've added a reproducable answer?

Comment: Also added the dplyr package call for the select function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have `NA` entries is the `emp_length` column, which you cannot include in the dataset that you pass to `glmnet`. You either need to drop rows that contain `NA` values from your dataset, or impute them.

Here is some code that you can use to drop the values and get `glmnet` to work properly.

```
X = select(df, -outcome)
Y = df$outcome
X_train = as.matrix(X[1:50,])
Y_train = as.matrix(sample(0:1,50,replace=TRUE))

has_NA = apply(is.na(X_train), 1, any) #= 1 if any column in that row is NA
X_train = X_train[!has_NA,]
Y_train = Y_train[!has_NA,]

library(glmnet)    
model = glmnet(X_train, Y_train, family = "binomial")
```

Comment: Thanks.   Your solution didn't fix the problem.   Now that there's a reproducible example do you have any further insights?

Comment: It wasn't reproducible until you clarified that it was `dplyr::select`. You are also referring to raw_data which is not defined. I used `X = subset(df, ,-outcome); Y = df$outcome`. Your outcome variable is currently all zeros, so it doesn't seem like a very useful example.

Comment: @AME Yes your bug was due to the fact that you have `NA` entries in your `X` matrix. See my updated response. As @42 says though, you also have all 0s in your outcome, which is not useful, but it doesn't matter as `glmnet` still works.

Comment: @BerkU.. I got the same error when all of my outcomes were 0.